# Compiling Qt application for Android using CMake (not by Qt Creator)

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt, cmake

i have developed a Qt application on Desktop.

i ported it Android using Qt Creator and it worked.

i would like to compile the app using cmake.

1. compile app to library (change `ADD_EXECUTABLE` to `ADD_LIBRARY`)
2. connect it with Qt java bootstrap how?
3. build final APK (just a zip with special structure and files right?)
4. install it on device (`adb install`)

i can do 1, 3 (some what) and 4.
i need help on 2
note: if someone describe all steps this would be great for other in future as well as me to correct myself

reason to not use Qt creator further:
im not a big fan of compiling everything everytime (just because 1 line of code changed), thrashing my machine just to get me a good looking IDE, nor i find qmake very much useful and intreresting.

Qt is one good pie that i like. :)

Qt 5.2.1

Linux localhost.localdomain 3.13.11-100.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 23 20:10:57 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux